# How to remove grails database

Tags: java, mysql, grails

I am looking to remove old data from my grails database that is un-useable after an update.  I know where my DB is saved too and it contains raq mysql files, are these alright to just delete?  If it comes down to it I could wire in a delete all type of thing but id rather be able to delete the old data without doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's good practice to delete database file by the file system. You should use a Database Management System (MySQL workbench, or Heidi SQL,...) to `drop` the database. That will delete all your database, then just re-create a new one.

Comment: So connect to the DB and query to drop the data in the tables?  That seems like an easy and quick way to get rid of it, thanks!

Comment: @user618194: It seems I misunderstand your question & you seems to mis-understand my answer, but well, it's ok. Yes you can use Database Management Systems to connect & query to delete data. Just don't drop the database, because it will delete all the table as well as the data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use create-drop option in the datasource file something like

```
development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'

        }
    }
```

Comment: The only issue I have with this is I have multiple tables on database with existing data in other tables that I want to keep, i'm worried if I add create-drop it will drop all info when I upload an update.

Comment: In that case delete all your unneeded data and then in the BootStrap you can then update your data or insert data as the case maybe. You can then resport to the update option in the DataSource.groovy file